# Broker disconnected in ec2

Tags: apache-kafka

The below configuration is working fine on my local windows using docker and docker-compose. I am facing issues when I deploy it on the ec2. This is the kafka configuration. I have also included the docker-compose.yml file for reference. When running the docker containers on ec2, the zookeeper, spring-boot-app and zookeeper services are running. but for the kafka service it gives an error stating broker disconnected.

```
server.port=9000
# spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/kaifd
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false


# Kafka Producer Configuration
 spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9093
 spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9093
 spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
 spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

# Kafka Consumer Configuration
 spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9093
 spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
 spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
 spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
 spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=com.kaif.dockersringboot.entities
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
 version: "3"
 services:
   zookeeper:
     image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
     container_name: zookeeper
     ports:
       - "2181:2181"

   kafka:
     image: wurstmeister/kafka
     container_name: kafka
     ports:
       - "9092:9092"
     environment:
       KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
       KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
       KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
       KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
       KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

   spring-boot-app:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     image: imageone
     container_name: imageone_container
     ports:
       - "9000:9000"
     depends_on:
       - kafka
     environment:
       SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9093
       SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/kaifd
       SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
       SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root

   postgres:
     image: postgres
     container_name: postgres_container
     ports:
       - "5432:5432"
     environment:
       POSTGRES_DB: kaifd
       POSTGRES_USER: postgres
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
```